# Kivy BoxLayout size_hint not working?

Tags: python, kivy, boxlayout, sizehint

i observed that size_hint_x doesn't work in BoxLayout, e.g.

```
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        Size_hint_x: #any value above zero has same effect, it streches to full x axis width.
```

or

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        Size_hint_y: #any value above zero has same effect, it streches to full y axis width.
```

same for Popup, if i put value to zero it sets to a particular height or width, but if i use screen it works correctly.

Am i missing something according to BoxLayout?

Answer (score 1):

> it streches to full x axis width

It stretches to full x axis only if `Button` is single element inside `BoxLayout`: it can't resize button since there's nothing to fill space of layout with.

Add at least some empty `FloatLayout` to achieve effect you want:

```
BoxLayout:    
    FloatLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'test'
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
```

Comment: yes i did it with empty Box layouts but in this case code becomes more and more complex.